# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -<library>

Tags: cuda, caffe

I am getting the error while running make-and-install.sh caffe . I have linked the /usr/local/cuda/libcudart.so to /usr/lib/libcudart.so and other files also

```
g++ .build_release/tools/caffe.o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/lib -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lboost_system -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lpthread -lboost_thread -lopenblas
g++ .build_release/tools/dump_network.o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a -o .build_release/tools/dump_network.bin -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/lib -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lboost_system -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lpthread -lboost_thread -lopenblas
g++ .build_release/tools/extract_features.o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/lib -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lboost_system -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lpthread -lboost_thread -lopenblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcublas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurand
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/tools/extract_features.bin] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcublas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurand
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/tools/dump_network.bin] Error 1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcublas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurand
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/tools/caffe.bin] Error 1
g++ .build_release/tools/caffe.o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/lib -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lboost_system -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lpthread -lboost_thread -lopenblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcublas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurand
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/tools/caffe.bin] Error 1
tarun@tarun-Inspiron-3542:~/Desktop/SA_project/sirius-caffe$ ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.so.7.5 /usr/lib/libcuda.so.7.5
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/lib/libcuda.so.7.5’: File exists
tarun@tarun-Inspiron-3542:~/Desktop/SA_project/sirius-caffe$ sudo ./make-and-install.s
sudo: ./make-and-install.s: command not found
tarun@tarun-Inspiron-3542:~/Desktop/SA_project/sirius-caffe$ sudo ./make-and-install.sh
g++ .build_release/tools/caffe.o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/lib -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lboost_system -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lpthread -lboost_thread -lopenblas
g++ .build_release/tools/dump_network.o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a -o .build_release/tools/dump_network.bin -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/lib -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lboost_system -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lpthread -lboost_thread -lopenblas
g++ .build_release/tools/extract_features.o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/lib -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lboost_system -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lpthread -lboost_thread -lopenblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcublas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurand
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/tools/extract_features.bin] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcublas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurand
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcublas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurand
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/tools/dump_network.bin] Error 1
make: *** [.build_release/tools/caffe.bin] Error 1
g++ .build_release/tools/caffe.o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/lib -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lboost_system -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lpthread -lboost_thread -lopenblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcublas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurand
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/tools/caffe.bin] Error 1
```

any kind of help will be appreciated.

Is there some problem with the libraries or the path .

**Edit to add**

```
ls -l /usr/lib/cu*

total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 29 22:11 backend
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 11 11:07 backend-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 11 11:07 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 11 11:07 daemon
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 11 11:07 driver
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 11 11:07 filter
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 11 11:07 monitor
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 11 11:07 notifier
```

Comment: The g++ compile command line is missing a switch: `-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64`

Comment: edit your post with the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/cu*`.  Additionally, do `file /usr/lib/libcudart.so` (I'm guessing that your link (`ln`) is invalid.

Comment: @RobertCrovella - ah ha, so this requires specific knowledge of this library package I assume? (which creates the inability to link to the other archives)

Comment: @KevinDTimm you are right , file /usr/lib/libcudart.so shows broken link, how to correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit your post with the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/cu*`. Additionally, do `file /usr/lib/libcudart.so` (I'm guessing that your link (ln) is invalid.**

^^^^^ Already done ^^^^^

As the broken link is confirmed, go to the `/usr/lib/` directory and link (`ln`) again.

`ln -s /usr/local/cuda/libcudart.so /usr/lib/libcudart.so`

do this step for all desired libraries.
As mentioned by @RobertCrovella, it appears there is some library knowledge required too, so add `-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64`.

Now, after typing all of that out, I would recommend not moving/linking any files, just add `-L /usr/local/cuda -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64` which will find all of your cuda libraries.

Comment: ln -s /usr/local/cuda/libcudart.so /usr/lib/libcudart.so  is forming broken links again and again . What may be the reason ?

Comment: because scattering about symbolic links is not a good way to fix the problem.

Comment: @RobertCrovella The things  Sounds good you were explaining, but due to lack of knowlege I am not getting , If you could explain in detail or provide link to some resources I can read about